# Change element CSS style with click of button

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to toggle the width of a div with a button.

Desired effect would be clicking 'Big' makes the div width 100% and the button reads 'Small' to reduce the div back to 50%.

[Live example - JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvXyL/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
    block 50%
</div>
<button>Big</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.block {
    background: green;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
}
button {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't see any jQuery code so I suggest you take a look at this http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/css-styling-dimensions/

Comment: Im trying to toggle styles of the green div by clicking the 'Big' button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(
$('#resize').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).html();
    if(value=='Big'){
        $(this).html('Small'); 
        $('div').css('width',"100%");
    }else{
    $(this).html('Big');
    $('div').css('width',"50%");
    }

})
)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tvXyL/6/

Comment: You're passing an incorrect argument to `$(document).ready`. You should wrap what you're passing right now in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use JavaScript for this job. From what I see you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (as you tagged it), so this might work for you:

```
// Give the button a default state
$('button').attr('data-state', 'expand');

$('button').click(function () {
    // When clicked

    if ($(this).attr('data-state') === 'expand') {

        // If it's in "expand" status, expand the div
        $('.block').css('width', '100%');
        $(this).text('Small').attr('data-state', 'compress');
    } else if ($(this).attr('data-state') === 'compress') {

        // If it's in "compress" state, compress the div
        $('.block').css('width', '50%');
        $(this).text('Big').attr('data-state', 'expand');
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2UzG2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this jQuery to simply toggle classes.

**jQuery**

```
$('button').on('click', function(event) {
    if($('.block').hasClass('expand') == false) {
        $('.block').addClass('expand');
        $(this).text('Small');
    } else {
        $('.block').removeClass('expand');
        $(this).text('Big');
    }
});
```

Add an .expand class to your CSS.

**CSS**

```
.block.expand {
    width: 100%;
}
```

JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RyN7d/1/